# How can I extract a filename from a path using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, string, operator-precedence

I have a Perl variable I populate from the database. Its name is `$path`. I need to get another variable `$file` which has just the filename from the pathname.

I tried:

```
$file = $path =~ s/.*\///;
```

I am very new to Perl.

Answer (score 43):

Why reinvent the wheel? Use the [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) module:

```
use File::Basename;
...
$file = basename($path);
```

---

Why did `$file=$path=~s/.*\///;` not work?

`=~` has higher [precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) than `=`

So

```
$file = $path =~s/.*\///;
```

is treated as:

```
$file = ($path =~s/.*\///);
```

which does the replacement in `$path` and assigns either `1` (if replacement occurs) or `''` (if no replacement occurs).

What you want is:

```
($file = $path) =~s/.*\///;
```

which assigns the value of `$path` to `$file` and then does the replacement in `$path`.

But again there are many problems with this solution:

1. It is incorrect. A filename in Unix based systems (not sure about Windows) can contain newline. But `.` by default does not match a newline. So you'll have to use a `s` modifier so that `.` matches newline as well:

   ```
   ($file = $path) =~s/.*\///s;
   ```
2. Most importantly it is not portable as it is assuming `/` is the path separator which is not the case with some platforms like Windows (which uses `\`), Mac (which uses `:`). So use the module and let it handle all these issues for you.

Comment: Agreed. Generally better using a module like this than a regex as it is cross platform.

Comment: Also note that File::Basename is a core module, and has always been in Perl 5 so it doesn't need to be installed.

Comment: The man page about File::Basename, recommends to use `fileparse` method for this task, becuase "[basename] does NOT always return the file name portion of a path as you might expect"

Answer (score 3):

```
use File::Basename
```

Check the below link for a detailed description on how it works:

http://p3rl.org/File::Basename

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way of doing this is -

```
use File::Basename;

my $file_name = basename($0);
```

So the variable `$file_name` will have the name of your script

Answer (score 1):

[Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path%3a%3aClass) may seem like overkill at first—making objects of file and dir paths—but it can really pay off in complicated scripts and offers lots of bonuses that will prevent spaghetti when you get backed into a corner by scope creep. [File::Spec](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aSpec) is used in the first example for fun to resolve path.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Path::Class qw( file );
use File::Spec;

# Get the name of the current script with the procedural interface-
my $self_file = file( File::Spec->rel2abs(__FILE__) );
print
    " Full path: $self_file", $/,
    "Parent dir: ", $self_file->parent, $/,
    " Just name: ", $self_file->basename, $/;

# OO                                    
my $other = Path::Class::File->new("/tmp/some.weird/path-.unk#");
print "Other file: ", $other->basename, $/;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url=~/\/([^\/]+)$/;
print "Filename $1\n";
```

Comment: To make for a better post, you might expand on your answer, explaining why that particular regex would work for various examples.  This will help your answer make sense to the original poster, _and_ to the many other future readers.

Answer (score 0):

As easy as that:

```
$path =~ /.*[\/\\](.*)/;    # will return 1 (or 0) and set $1
my $file = $1;              # $1 contains the filename
```

To check if an filename is available use:

```
$file = $1 if $path =~ /.*[\/\\](.*)/;
```

The pattern:

```
.*[\/\\](.*)
| |     |
| |     \- at last there is a group with the filename
| \------- it's the last / in linux or the last \ in windows
\--------- .* is very greedy, so it takes all it could
```

[Use e.g. https://regex101.com/ to check regular expressions.](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score -2):

Extracting file name from path is very easy for both Unix and Windows file systems without need any packages:

```
my $path;
$path = 'C:\A\BB\C\windows_fs.txt';     # Windows
#$path = '/a/bb/ccc/ddd/unix_fs.txt';    # Unix

my $file =  (split( /\/|\\/, $path))[-1];
print "File: $file\n";

# variable $file is "windows_fs.txt"  for Windows
# variable $file is "unix_fs.txt"     for Unix
```

The logic is very simple: create an array of all elements making the path and retrieve the last one. Perl allows to use negative indexes starting from end of the array. Index "-1" corresponds to the last element.

Comment: But File::Basename exists in the standard Perl library, so there's no good reason not to use it.

Comment: I had cases when I needed execute a Perl script where only perl.exe was available. Your approach won't work while mine will be working always.

Comment: If Perl is installed, then the standard Perl library will also be available. If it's not, you have a broken Perl installation and you should not use it for anything.